# How to secure SSN field while entering on a webform

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, webforms

When entering the SSN on the webform, I need the digit to appear for a couple of seconds and then have it go to an asterisk.

Is this possible? Please provide directions.

Comment: It is possible. In the tradition of StackOverflow you should show some code that you've tried and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something which is suggested here:
http://css-tricks.com/better-password-inputs-iphone-style/
there are 2 examples, one flashes the last digit entered, while keeping the textbox as asterisk.  other example keeps everything as asterisk except the last digit.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to this is changing the input type from `text` to `password` in the input's `change` event, with a `setTimeout` if needed.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77MeF/1/) for a simple example using jquery.

Comment: If the answer is not correct and deserves a -1, it'd be helpful to explain why.

Comment: Changing the `type` of an `<input />` doesn't work in IE. And the functionality you provided isn't what the OP seems to want anyways.

Comment: @Ian perhaps we are reading it differently then.

Comment: Who said anything about using the `change` event. The OP seems to want it to be as they type. And they only seem to reference a **digit**, not the full value. What the other posted suggests seems appropriate - similar to how an iPhone's password field acts

Comment: @Ian the OP also mentions nothing about using additional plugins or css.  But fine, I'll take a down vote for trying to answer an unclear question.

Comment: I'm not saying including a plugin/css is a great idea, but what the other answerer suggested seems to more closely do what the OP unclearly wants (if that makes sense). If custom code could do it, that would be great, but at the same time, why reinvent the wheel if it's already invented? And the downvote was specifically for the IE-incompatibility. Older versions of jQuery would throw an error, but since 2.* doesn't support old IE, it worked in your fiddle. Also, if the question's unclear, I'd suggest asking the OP questions to figure out more

Comment: @Ian I agree, and that's why I said I accept the down vote.

Comment: (sorry, I just wanted to explain myself more)

Comment: @WillP this is exactly what I need. The Iphone Style of entering password where it allows you to verify what you typed in and after a few seconds goes to an asterik.I am in the process of learning jquery and I did not know that Stackoverflow only helps if I only provided sample code.

Comment: @user1077595 Thanks, if it works for you, please mark it as the answer.  And yeah, on this site most feel that without trying things yourself first, that one is simply looking for free work to get done.  In this case, I'm not sure that's true, it looked to me more like shopping for possible methodologies (which I consider a valid use of the site).

Comment: @WillP this does not work in IE8. Is this a known problem?

Comment: @user1077595 yeah, as Ian pointed out that changing an input's `type` doesn't work in any version of IE.  If that's needed, then the other solution may be the one for you.